# Elementary set problem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$ be a set and $f$ a function $f:A \to A$. A set $B$ is called "solid" in $A$ if and only if $f(B) \subseteq B$. Prove that a set $A$ is finite if and only if there is a function $f:A\to A$ for which the only solid sets in $A$ are the empty set and the whole set $A$.

I've found this problem in a collection of olympic problems for high school students. I've been trying to solve it without success.

Thank you for your interest!

Comment: Try to start with left to right implication, and find a function $f$ that works.

Comment: In a finite set there always is a function of this kind. It is sufficient to consider a function that associates every element of the set $a_k$ to $a_{k+1}$, and the last element to $a_0$

Answer (score 1):

If $A = \{1, \dots, n\}$, try $f(k) = k+1 \mod n$.

Hint for the converse: if $A$ is non-empty, let $x \in A$, and let $B = \{f^n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Show that $B$ is solid.

Comment: why does $B$ solid imply that $A$ is finite?

Comment: @RobertCardona: It implies that $A = \{f^n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$, which in particular means that $x = f^n(x)$ for some $n \geq 1$, and this cyclicity implies that $A$ is finite.